Orthogonalization of symmetric non-degenerate bilinear forms
It is well-known that given a field $k$ with characteristic different from $2$, every symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $B$ over a finite-dimensional space can be orthogonalized. This means that one can find a basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ such that $B(v_i, v_j) = 0$ if and only if $i \neq j$.
Is the same true for infinite-dimensional spaces? Suppose $B$ is a continuous symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form over a Banach space. When can $B$ be orthogonalized? Is there a classification of all such forms? Can you give an example of a form that can not be orthogonalized?
I am especially interested in the case where $k = \mathbb{Q}_p$ the field of the $p$-adic numbers.

In the case when you have a countable basis ${v_i}$, the G-S process goes as usual and you get a sequence of vectors ${u_i}$ such that for every positive integer $n$, the span of ${u_1,\ldots,u_n}$ is the same as the span for ${v_1,\ldots,v_n}$. In the general case, you have to use transfinite induction and work with the completion of the partial spans. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Of course, I meant that the vectors ${u_i}$ that you obtain from G-S are orthogonal . . .

@FZaldivar But this works only using Bessel inequality, right? What if $B$ is a bilinear form over a general Banach space, or $k$ is not $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ for example?

The first part works just fine for any symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form. In the general case, you start with a possibly uncountable algebraic basis (whose existence follows from, e.g., Zorn's lemma) and then do transfinite induction as outlined in the Wikipedia article.

@FZaldivar One builds the sequence in the wiki recursively by setting $u_{\alpha} = v_{\alpha} - \sum_{\beta < \alpha} \langle v_{\alpha}, u_{\beta} \rangle u_{\beta}$, right? But this sum is not well-defined without some sort of Bessel inequality. This is where I am confused.
